# iOS 11 Safari input type="file" renaming file

Tags: ios, reactjs, safari, ios11, fileapi

I have a file upload input that I'm trying to extract the File object from in my `onChange` handler. I'm getting the File off `event.target.files[0]`. The File looks like the following in almost all browsers:

```
{
  lastModified: 1576686515483,
  lastModifiedDate: Wed Dec 18 2019 11:28:35 GMT-0000,
  name: "Screen Shot 2019-12-18.png",
  preview: "data:image/png;base64,...",
  size: 35000,
  type: "image/png",
  webkitRelativePath: "",
}
```

Problem: In iOS 11.1 Safari on iPhone X, the `name` is different every time I attempt to upload the same file. This is problematic for my application. I'm using the `name` to check for duplicate file uploads. I'm guessing this name change is a security feature in iOS 11+, as I'm unable to replicate in iOS 10.

Expected Behavior: I expect the `name` attribute of the File object to match the filename of the file being uploaded.

Comment: I noticed the same thing, did you ever find a solution? I also noticed that iOS Safari does not import the files in a consistent order, which is an issue for my app.